# Using XPATH to find elements with a certain attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML document. I want to build a query in XPath to find all the Ship elements for the Ships that were launched before 1917

```
 <Ships>
    <Class name="Kongo">
    <Ship name="h" launched="1915"/>
    <Ship name="h1" launched="1920"/>
    </Class>
    
    <Class name="Kongo2">
    <Ship name="h2" launched="1941"/>
    <Ship name="h3" launched="1941"/>
    </Class>
    <Class name="Kongo2">
    <Ship name="h4" launched="1917"/>
    <Ship name="h5" launched="1917"/>
    </Class>
    
    </Ships>
```

I came up with the following Xpath : `if(/Ships/Class/Ship/number(@launched) < 1917) then Ships/Class/Ship else ()` 
But this lists down all the Ship elements even though the if check is there. What could be wrong with this?

Comment: Your logic is "if there's a ship launched before 1917 then select all ships otherwise select none".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a predicate like this (only XPath-1.0 required):

```
/Ships/Class/Ship[1917 > @launched]
```

The predicate expression is inverted to avoid the less than char `<` which is problematic in some contexts. But the semantic stays the same as in `@launched < 1917`.

Comment: Could you help me with one more XQuery for finding the names of the Class with at least 3 ships?

Comment: Use `/Ships/Class[count(Ship) > 2]/@name`.